# Scala: How to initialize an abstract method that is supposed to return a future

Tags: scala

I am trying to interpret a body of existing Scala code. 
In this body of code I have a trait - that I call  MyUsefulTrait - that declares a couple of methods for whom I supply an implementation in the class I mix aforementioned trait.
My goal is simply to provide an initialization for these function so that my class compiles. Right now the IDE is complaining that I better give an implementation to these method or declare my class abstract.
And I would rather not declare my class abstract.

Ao, here are my method declarations that need to be given a default implementation:
Firstly. method 1 goes as follows:

```
def conveyFindingsOnFile: (MyFileInfo, AskReport) => FileHandledReport
```

where, 
MyFileInfo is a sealed trait that defines a couple of File metadata like path, when accessed last and its author.

and, AskReport is a case class that defines a few things like a Map, an exception message, etc.

And, lastly the FileHandledReport is a case class that defines things like some File metadata, based on some findings on the file handled.

I would like to provide a basic implementation or initialization, just to make the compiler happy .

My second method goes as follows:

```
    def doResearch:Option[(AskReport) => Future[AskReport]]
```

---

Based on the answer I get for the first method, i will try to figure out the default implementation for the second one. I will try to. But yes, I would like the second method to also be given some initialization. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole problem is very fuzzy. Could you post the code for `MyFileInfo`. `AskReport` and `FileHandledReport`? Also your `MyUsefulTrait`. And explain better what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: If you just want it to compile (and fail if the method is called at runtime) you can define a method as `???`. Otherwise you should, like, implement the method to do what you want it to do.

Comment: I will post the code. I agree it is fuzzy, but I did not realize it until you reminded me about it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you mention, you only want to

> (...) provide an initialization for these function so that my class compiles (...)

and

> (...) make the compiler happy (...)

then you can just make those methods return some useless value according to their respective return types. For example,

```
override def conveyFindingsOnFile: (MyFileInfo, AskReport) ⇒ FileHandledReport = (a,b) ⇒ FileHandledReport(/* fill default values for the case class members here */)
override def doResearch: Option[(AskReport) ⇒ Future[AskReport]] = None
```

as long as you will not use them. Alternatively, you can use the built-in method `???` whose return type is `Nothing` (which is a subtype of any other type) and throws an `NotImplementedError` exception if you try to use those methods:

```
override def conveyFindingsOnFile: (MyFileInfo, AskReport) ⇒ FileHandledReport = ???
override def doResearch: Option[(AskReport) ⇒ Future[AskReport]] = ???
```

Moreover, this is the default action of IntelliJ IDEA, in case you are working with it. Hope it helped.

Comment: Yes, I am working with Intellij. I should have mentioned this fact in the first place. Yes, your explanation and code did help. Thanks. Excellent explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is easier because you can simply write

```
def doResearch:Option[(AskReport) => Future[AskReport]] = None
```

From the first one you have to return function taking `(MyFileInfo, AskReport)` and returning `FileHandledReport`. If you know what `FileHandledReport` should be, you can go with:

```
def foo(MyFileInfo, AskReport): FileHandledReport = ... //code 
def conveyFindingsOnFile: (MyFileInfo, AskReport) => FileHandledReport = foo
```

Comment: Yes, I have been very confused by the signature/declaration of the first one. One of my theories was that, it looked like a map. You are right about that, I do know what FileHandledReport is. Excellent answer